# Display list of installed plugins in Wordpress admin area

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, code-snippets

I would like to find a way of displaying a list of all my installed plugin in a neat widget on the home admin area of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often when I'm doing performance audits on websites I like to clearly see exactly what I'm working with and having a complete list of plugins whereby I can copy and paste into an Google doc or sheet is really handy so I can go through the list and see what plugins I can remove, upgrade, and keep.

This solution is an adaptation of a similar solution [found here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54742/how-to-do-i-get-a-list-of-active-plugins-on-my-wordpress-blog-programmatically)

However, that solution only displays active plugins and not a complete list. For example plugins like Easy Updates Manager wouldn't show as it's only admin-based.

The solution below shows a complete list of all installed plugins. Regardless whether they are active or not.

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_54742_wp_dashboard_setup');

function wpse_54742_wp_dashboard_setup() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'wpse_54742_active_site_plugins', __( 'Installed Plugins' ), 'wpse_54742_active_site_plugins' );
}

function wpse_54742_active_site_plugins() {
    $all_plugins = get_plugins();
    $active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $active_plugins as $index => $plugin ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $plugin, $all_plugins ) ) {
            //var_export( $all_plugins[ $plugin ] );
            echo '<h4 style="margin-bottom:15px;font-weight:400;font-size:12px">', $all_plugins[ $plugin ][ 'Name' ], ' ('. $all_plugins[ $plugin ][ 'Version' ] .')</h4>';
            
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Unless you have a child theme installed, I wouldn't recommend adding this to your functions.php file. Instead, use a plugin like [code snippets](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) if you want to have better control over your code snippets.

Hope this helps some of you as I feel this is pretty handy to have. Equally, if any has a more elegant solution, I'd love to hear about it.